Change of numeraire and the adjustment to the growth rate in terms of the numeraire ratio
I'm working with a process $f$ and considering how its drift adjusts when moving between different numeraires. Here’s what I have so far:
Process $f$ with numeraire $g$:

The process $f$ has a drift of $f \cdot \lambda \cdot \sigma_f \, dt$ under a real world measure.
with numeraire $g$, the process $d\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)$ has a drift (again under a real world measure):
$$ 
  \frac{f}{g} \left( (\sigma_f - \sigma_g)(\lambda - \sigma_g) \right) dt
  $$

Process $f$ with numeraire $h$:

When switching to numeraire $h$, the drift of $f$ is now $f \cdot \lambda^* \cdot \sigma_f \, dt$ (under a real world measure).
with numeraire $h$, the process $d\left(\frac{f}{h}\right)$ has a drift (under a real world measure):
$$
  \frac{f}{h} \left( (\sigma_f - \sigma_h)(\lambda^* - \sigma_h) \right) dt
  $$

Ratio between $h$ and $g$:

I know the dynamics of the numeraire ratio $d\left(\frac{h}{g}\right)$ are given by:
$$
  d\left(\frac{h}{g}\right) = \left( \lambda^* \sigma_h - \lambda \sigma_g + \sigma_g^2 - \sigma_h \sigma_g \right) \frac{h}{g} dt + (\sigma_h - \sigma_g) \frac{h}{g} dz
  $$
From this, I deduce that:
$$
  \sigma_w = (\sigma_h - \sigma_g)
  $$
where w = h/g

Question:
I also know that the adjustment to the drift of $f$ when moving from numeraire $g$ to numeraire $h$ is $(\lambda^* - \lambda) \sigma_f$.
But I want to express this change in drift of f in terms of the volatility of the numeraire ratio:
$$
\alpha_f = \sigma_w \cdot \sigma_f
$$
How can I prove this result?
Side note: I can then show that this result is equal to the instantaneous covariance of w and f.

First of all, regardless what $f$ and $g$ are, we have (integration-by-parts)
$$\tag1
d\left(\frac fg\right)=\frac {df}{g}+f\,\,d\left(\frac 1g\right)+d\left\langle f,\frac 1g \right\rangle_t\,.
$$
If these processes are of the form
$$\tag2
df=\mu_f\,dt+\sigma_f\,dW^f_t\,,\quad dg=\mu_g\,dt+\sigma_g\,dW^g_t
$$
then (by Ito)
$$\tag3
d\left(\frac 1g\right)=-\frac{dg}{g^2}+\frac{d\langle g\rangle_t}{g^3}
=-\frac{\mu_g\,dt+\sigma_g\,dW^g_t}{g^2}+\frac{\sigma_g^2\,dt}{g^3}\,.
$$
Can you proceed to figure out the drift of $\dfrac fg\,?$
Hint: the drift of $\frac fg$ is obtained from putting the expressions (2) and (3) into (1):
\begin{align}\tag6
d\left(\frac fg\right)=\frac{\mu_f\,dt+\sigma_f\,dW^f_t}g-f\frac{\mu_g\,dt+\sigma_g\,dW^g_t}{g^2}+f\frac{\sigma^2_g\,dt}{g^3}-\frac {\sigma_f\,\sigma_g}{g^2}\,d\langle W^f,W^g\rangle_t\,.
\end{align}
If $W^f$ and $W^g$ are correlated with $\rho$ the drift becomes
$$\tag5
\left\{
\frac{\mu_f}g-f\frac{\mu_g}{g^2}+f\frac{\sigma_g^2}{g^3}-\frac{\sigma_f\,\sigma_g\,\rho}{g^2}\right\}\,.
$$

Even if I assume $\rho=1$ and $\mu_f=f\lambda\sigma_f$ (like you do) I can for the life of me not related this to your claim that the drift of
$d\left(\dfrac fg\right)$ is
$$\tag6
\frac{f}{g} \left( (\sigma_f - \sigma_g)(\lambda - \sigma_g) \right)\,dt\,.
$$

What do you assume about $\mu_g\,?$ Give all your definitions and do some work.



Yes, it is given in the original post, under the first headline.
Also note that the two Wiener processes are the same, otherwise you would not get the above equation for the numeraire ratio d(h/g)

@JonasBemt I am having strong doubts about that. Also: getting closer to your question: what on earth is $\sigma_w,?$

w = h/g. I will clarify that in the original post.
